# Use multiple google maps API account to exceed the limit?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps Api with javascript (client call api). Other hand, They have a limit of 2500 requests / day. I don't know the limit per a client or a domain or a token.

So, can I use multiple  google maps API account to exceed the limit?

Comment: If this is against google's terms of service you probably won't get an answer to this on SO. Please check that first.

Answer (score 0):

API Keys are simply so you can track usage. API limits are determined by the hosting domain (read HTTP Referrer). So multiple keys won't help at all.